# are there anyway to prevent the OnAfterRenderAsync to run the JS function for every rendering in Blazor?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, blazor, rendering

I call jquery fun in my blazor app. I'm doing some services in Onin - I would like to call this function in my razor component. I did use the following code in the component. The function is showing when the page has loaded. But when I doing any clicking or changing any value in the page, even like a change a text that not related to the function, the function existed every time. Any hint?

```
 protected override  void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        
            
              if(!firstRender)
    {
           await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("TextArea.AddLineToTextArea");
           
     }
```

You may wonder why I put (!firstRender), the reason is that by default the firstRender is false, and I don't know the reason. Some people say ,According to this [Blazor Component Reference Null on First Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828878/blazor-component-reference-null-on-first-render), that if your component in if/else it will cause the issue. but mine is out side

here is my function is adding a linenumber to textarea.

```
window.TextArea = {
    
    AddLineToTextArea:function(){

        $(".lined").linedtextarea(
            {selectedLine: 1}
          );
        
          // Target a single one
          $("#inpDefinition").linedtextarea();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reverse the if condition you should have what you need:

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("TextArea.AddLineToTextArea");
        }
    }
```

This code means that the await `JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("TextArea.AddLineToTextArea");` statement will be executed only once, when the component has it first rendering.

The method `OnAfterRender` is executed everytime the component is updated, for example a user click on a button or whatever. But the boolean parameter `firstRender` is equal to true for the first rendering, and will be false after.